# ChunkyPNG: Is it possible to read an image directly from a URL?

Tags: ruby, heroku, chunkypng

I tried (with some success)

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'chunky_png'

image_url = "http://res.cloudinary.com/houlihan-lokey/image/upload/c_limit,h_75,w_120/ixl7z4c1czlvrqnbt0mm.png"
# image_url = "http://res.cloudinary.com/houlihan-lokey/image/upload/c_limit,h_75,w_120/zqw2pgczdzbtyj3aib2o.png" # this works

image_file = open(image_url)
image = ChunkyPNG::Image.from_file(image_file)
puts image.width
```

Some images work, others don't. The error:

```
TypeError: no implicit conversion of StringIO into String
from /Users/theuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/chunky_png-1.3.3/lib/chunky_png/datastream.rb:66:in `initialize'
from /Users/theuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/chunky_png-1.3.3/lib/chunky_png/datastream.rb:66:in `open'
from /Users/theuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/chunky_png-1.3.3/lib/chunky_png/datastream.rb:66:in `from_file'
from /Users/theuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/chunky_png-1.3.3/lib/chunky_png/canvas/png_decoding.rb:53:in `from_file'
from (irb):5
from /Users/theuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
```

I will be running this on Heroku and am wondering -- is there a reliable way to achieve this without creating temporary files?

Comment: Can you tell what you mean with "don't work"? Is there an error, something in the logs? If it does not work, are you able to load that file locally, without redirections?

Comment: @spickermann, I added the error message above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with files which were too small for `open` to create a temp file for.

The solution is to not rely on temp files but to read the image into memory and use ChunkyPNG's Image.from_blob:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'chunky_png'

image_url = "http://res.cloudinary.com/houlihan-lokey/image/upload/c_limit,h_75,w_120/ixl7z4c1czlvrqnbt0mm.png"

image_file = open(image_url).read
image = ChunkyPNG::Image.from_blob(image_file)
puts image.width
```

This may not work with large images, but is OK for my application.